# Webpack-dev-server runs correctly the first time but returns errors if ran a second

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run "npm run dev" which is dev: "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot" it runs correctly and even updates the page im working on. However if I end the process then in the same terminal run the command "npm run dev" a second time it returns an error!

[image]

I have only just started learning webpack/react/node so I don't know whats going on.

Comment: Something is already running on port 8080. How are you ending the previous process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably has another webpack server running or it was not properly shut down, so the address (127.0.0.1:8080) is in use. See the error message.

Comment: So when I shut down the server it doesn't actually shut and keep going for some reason?

Comment: Maybe. You can check your processes and localhost port usage.

Comment: How do I do that I'm new to this.... also I think it is that because when I shut down the cli then reopen it and run the command it works again

Comment: That's a whole set of questions about the usage of command line tools that I probably couldn't fit the answers here... :( You can google to find some help.